# Find Distinct IP Addresses Based on First Two Octets?

Tags: arrays, ip

I have an array on `IP` addresses tracking logins and I want to find out how many of them are distinct. However, often there will be logins from the `IP` address of `X.Y.1.2` and `X.Y.2.4`. That typically means it's coming from the same local area, ISP, or organization. For our purposes, we do not want to treat those as distinct.

How can I filter out `IP` addresses with the same first two octets?

Comment: Programming language?

Comment: John H : I just realized that you did not mark any answer to your questions as "accepted". Please do so, if a question is answered to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since the language is not given, I'll try it with a shell script. Assume that all the IP addresses are in a text file called "ipaddresses.txt":

```
cut -d . -f 1-2 ipaddresses.txt | sort | uniq
```

EDIT: since it has to be in an array, I'll try in python:

```
>>> addr = ['1.2.3.4', '1.2.55.66', '33.22.11.0', '33.22.11.1']
>>> print set(['.'.join(x.split('.')[0:2]) for x in addr])
set(['33.22', '1.2'])
>>> # just show how many:
>>> print len(set(['.'.join(x.split('.')[0:2]) for x in addr]))
2
```

Answer (score 0):

In ruby

```
ip = ['1.2.3.4', '1.2.3.5', '10.111.12.13','1.9.1.2']

ip.collect{|a| a.split('.')[0..1].join('.')}.uniq
```

Output

```
["1.2", "10.111", "1.9"]
```